# Pivoting without known column name

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following table with data:

```
A   B
=== ===
M   2  
M   3
M   5
N   5
N   2
O   6
P   13
P   7
P   9
P   11
P   3
```

Now I need a PIVOT (?) query to:

- Group by column A.
- Sort on column B.
- Take the lowest 3 values from column B.
- Put these values in the new columns B1, B2, B3

So the result will be:

```
A   B1   B2   B3
=== ==== ==== ====
M   2    3    5
N   2    5    null
O   6    null null
P   3    7    9
```

So far I have been trying to create queries with TOP, GROUP BY, PIVOT. I think the best way to go is with the PIVOT, but since I do not have a value I can use as a column name, I am stuck. Also, making a top-3 selection of these values seems also pretty challenging.

*** EDIT ***

Their is a unique constraint on columns A and B, so the values for B are always unique for the same A.

Comment: Which database are you using?  Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Oracle. I removed the incorrect tag.

Comment: @MartinMulder What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach that works with both Oracle and SQL Server (the original question was tagged with both databases).

You can just enumerate the `b` values for each `a` using `dense_rank()` (or `row_number()`, but `dense_rank()` will give three different values if there are duplicates).  Then pivot using conditional aggregation:

```
with ab as (
      select a, b,
             dense_rank() over (partition by a order by b asc) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then b end) as b1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then b end) as b2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then b end) as b3
from ab
group by a;
```

EDIT:

The question is unclear on what to do if there are duplicates.  For instance, if the data in `b` is 1, 1, 2, 3.  Which should be the three columns?

```
1, 2, 3
```

or
    1, 1, 2

The use of `dense_rank()` puts three different values into the columns (the first possible result).  The use of `row_number()` would put the three smallest values (the second result).  If there are never any duplicate values, then `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` produce the same results.

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` doesn't work that way (at least in SQL Server), it will give the same value if there are duplicates. `ROW_NUMBER` on the other hand does behaves as you want

Comment: @Lamak . . . I meant that `dense_rank()` would give three different values of `b` if there are duplicates.  `row_number()` would repeat the values of `b`.  It is unclear what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I'm saying that's not right, `dense_rank` will return the same value in case of a duplicate and `row_number` won't

Comment: @Lamak . . . Say you have 1, 1, 2, 3.  The question is:  do you want 1, 2, 3 (`dense_rank()`) or (1, 1, 2) (`row_number()`).  I interpret the phrase "lowest 3 values" in the OP as "lowest 3 distinct values".  Any idea why this was downvoted by the way?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, I get what you are saying now, wasn't clear from your explanation, you could add that to your answer (it's not my downvote, but I think that it was the partitioning)

Comment: The values in B cannot be duplicate for the same A. So there is a unique key for the columns A+B.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result, but I would also implement a windowing function similar to `row_number()` to get the final result.  The `row_number()` function will create a unique sequenced number for each `B` value if you partition the data over the `A` column.  This sequenced number will be used as the new column names:

```
select a, B1, B2, B3
from
(
  select a, b,
    row_number() over(partition by a
                      order by b) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(b)
  for seq in ('1' as B1, '2' as B2, '3' as B3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86b92/4). This will give a result:

```
| A | B1 |     B2 |     B3 |
|---|----|--------|--------|
| M |  2 |      3 |      5 |
| N |  2 |      5 | (null) |
| O |  6 | (null) | (null) |
| P |  3 |      7 |      9 |
```